# Subdomain for admin panel with single apache instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have currently main site running at example.com
and I would like to create admin panel for example.com at subdomain admin.example.com. My domain is with google domains, and site is hosted on aws ec2 instance.

I tried creating `<VirtualHost> </VirtualHost>` entry in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file and pointed the second entry to /var/www/html/another site folder.  but im not sure what ip to point the subdomain to.